# Unable to add cluster through RKE https://rancher-webhook.cattle-system.svc:443/v1/webhook/validation?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Not able to create cluster using existing nodes (RKE) on rancher 2.5.10. Firewall is disabled by default on all the servers.

Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "rancherauth.cattle.io": Post https://rancher-webhook.cattle-system.svc:443/v1/webhook/validation?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

reference: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/troubleshooting/expired-webhook-certificates/

```sh
kubectl delete secret -n cattle-system cattle-webhook-tls
kubectl delete mutatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io --ignore-not-found=true rancher.cattle.io
kubectl delete pod -n cattle-system -l app=rancher-webhook
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).